# Is it possible to access data across 2 different iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, ios

Let's say that I store some ID data in App1 and want to access it in App2 on the same device. Is this possible on the platform? Are there any workarounds for this if not?

Comment: Have you considered iCloud or Dropbox?

Comment: An app can respond to a particular type of URL, so App1 can register to respond to App1://foo/bar urls and App2 can access that url.

Comment: @BrianWillis what if the device doesn't have iCloud or Dropbox?

Comment: @PaulTomblin, but if you had to deal with multiple installations of the app, how can you deal with this without using the deprecated UDID?

Comment: @cfarm54, How can you have multiple installations of an app on a single device?

Comment: @PaulTomblin if you have device1 with App1 and App2 and device2 with App1 and App2 how can you make sure your URL/service doesn't mix up the data between the devices?

Comment: Because they only work on the same device.  Which is exactly what you asked for in your question.

Comment: sorry i might be misunderstanding then. it sounds like i'll need to learn more about what URLs can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image Share Between **My app** to **Instagram**:

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalImageView.image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];        
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savedImagePath];

    UIDocumentInteractionController * docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    docController.delegate = self;
    [docController retain];
    docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
    [docController setURL:imageUrl];
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [iOS keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1). Here's a good tutorial on [keychain access groups](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/3/keychain-group-access.html).

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to register apps as handling some filetype. When such file is about to be opened, a user gets the choice of apps that can handle it and the chosen app gets a copy of the file copied to it's `~Documents/Inbox` directory. But i think you're better with some external service.