# How to share files between 2 local ios apps without url scheme or external server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-sharing

I have 2 local app "A" and "B". I want that the application "A" call the application "B" and "B" send a response to "A" with a file.

Url scheme is a good solution to call Application "B" but it's a bad solution to send files to "A".

How do I send a file from one application to another without url scheme and without external server ?

Comment: I don't think it's allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other than URL option, you have an best option to use iOS [keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1). See this [article](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/03/keychain-group-access.html).

There are couple of other options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920181/is-it-possible-to-access-data-across-2-different-ios-apps).

Another option is to use [iCloud](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH2-SW1) APIs.

One more, copy-paste data between Apps using [UIPasteboard](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2012/03/26/a-way-to-share-data-between-apps-on-a-given-ios-device/).

BTW what's the problem with URL solution? Apple suggest you to use [URL to share data between different Apps.](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html)

Comment: Keychain is a good idea but application "A" is make by other people, so I can't give access to keychain

Comment: Edited my answer. Use iCloud otherwise you are out of options!! Apple suggest you to use URL solution!

Comment: Found one more option to use copy-paste data between the apps. May be useful for you :)

Answer (score 3):

I've used a combination of custom URL schemes and a UIPasteboard. I recently posted a full tutorial at http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/.

Comment: Hey Dilan, your website seems to be down. If you are no longer maintaining the site, do you by and chance have the content available that you could PM me?