# Sharing data in between apps in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, data-sharing

I have a task to share data between apps in the same device. May be both apps can use a shared database on same device. How to share Data between two apps in IOS. Anybody have done it in any    way. 
Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Check out [this link](http://www.enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/). It is based in Objective-C but the same concept still applies.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK I think that article is obsolete, since iOS 8, App groups are the official way to do it.

Comment: I am talking about App groups. have you implemented this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can turn on App group on your App Project capabilities tab on both of your apps with the same group container ID. "group.com.yourCompanyID.sharedDefaults"

[image]

Then you can access the same folder from your apps using the following url:

```
let sharedContainerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.yourCompanyID.sharedDefaults")!
```

So if you would like to share a switch state from two different apps you should do it as follow:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var sharedSwitch: UISwitch!
    let switchURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.yourCompanyID.sharedDefaults")!
        .appendingPathComponent("switchState.plist")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(switchURL.path)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateSwitch), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
    }
    func updateSwitch(_ notofication: Notification) {
        sharedSwitch.isOn = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: switchURL.path) as? Bool == true
    }
    @IBAction func switched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        let success = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(sender.isOn, toFile: switchURL.path)
        print(success)
    }
}
```