# Cannot retrieve data from NSUserDefaults into today extension (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, today-extension

I have a group of arrays that all contain a number of instances of a custom Task object that I have created. I am saving the arrays to NSUserDefaults as follows:

**Custom Task Object**

```
class Task:NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name:String
    var notes:String
    var date:NSDate
    var dateUse:Bool
    var taskCompleted:Bool

    init(name:String, notes:String, date:NSDate, dateUse:Bool, taskCompleted:Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.notes = notes
        self.date = date
        self.dateUse = dateUse
        self.taskCompleted = taskCompleted
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
        self.name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.notes = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("notes") as! String
        self.date = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("date") as! NSDate
        self.dateUse = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("dateUse") as! Bool
        self.taskCompleted = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("taskCompleted") as! Bool
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encodeObject(self.notes, forKey: "notes")
        coder.encodeObject(self.date, forKey: "date")
        coder.encodeObject(self.dateUse, forKey: "dateUse")
        coder.encodeObject(self.taskCompleted, forKey: "taskCompleted")
    }
}
```

---

**Saving:**

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.myGroupName")

let nowData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(nowTasks)
defaults!.setObject(nowData, forKey: "nowData")
```

**Retrieving**

```
let nowDataPull = defaults!.objectForKey("nowData") as? NSData
if let nowDataPull2 = nowDataPull{
   let nowTasks2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(nowDataPull2) as? [Task]
   if let nowTasks21 = nowTasks2{
      nowTasks = nowTasks21
   }
}
```

The above method works fine for setting and retrieving data from the iPhone itself. However, this method does not work when trying to retrieve the data via the today extension.

When trying to retrieve from the today extension's .swift file I get the following errors:

> - Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 52550: (null)
> - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '* -[NSKeyedUnarchiver
>     decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (MyAppName.Task)
>     for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a
>     library that is not linked'

---

I know that the extension can read the data because when I call:

```
if (defaults?.objectForKey("nowData") != nil){
   print("there is data")
}
```

I get the printed response..

---

I can successfully save an Integer and retrieve via the today extension, but not `objectForKey`

---

I have tried various other saving methods including .plist files, but nothing seems to work. The same errors keep occurring. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I notice that the error refers to `MyAppName.Task`. Perhaps the Task class belongs to a different Module when compiled within the Today Extension?

Comment: @MikePollard I have the entire Task class declaration inside of a file called "sharedCode.swift". This file is "checked" with Target Membership for both the main app and the today extension..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround:**

So I have found a workaround (which is actually more efficient) for my problem. Because the decoding of `[Task]` was causing problems, I decided to go ahead and retrieve the data from an array that did not have objects inside of it, but rather just `NSDate()` instances. Because of this I can now save and access the important aspects of data that the today extension needs. I urge anyone else who is having issues with custom class decoding to try and simplify your data if at all possible in order to retrieve and use it in your extension. I am not exactly sure what the problem was or is, but retrieving simple data from an array stored in `NSUserDefaults` works without problems.

Hope all of this nonsense can help someone else out there!

Comment: I am leaning towards doing the same thing as well. In my case I know the custom class is linked to both the App and the Today Extension but archiving and unarchiving only works within the iPhone app itself. I can't help but feel that there has to be a better way to go about this!!

Comment: I had this same exact issue. After trying for days I eventually found another solution. You may want to consider doing that as well.

Answer (score 5):

another way is to fix the name of the class used for NSCoding. You simply have to use:

- `NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Task", forClass: Task.self` before serializing
- `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Task.self, forClassName: "Task")` before deserializing

wherever needed.

Looks like iOS extensions prefix the class name with the extension's name.

Comment: This is the most general solution for iOS extensions (and should be the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

Set Object

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("iOS", forKey: "userNameKey")

defaults.setInteger(25, forKey: "Age")
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "UseTouchID")
defaults.setDouble(M_PI, forKey: "Pi")
```

Reading

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let name = defaults.stringForKey("userNameKey")
```

Comment: I don't think `standardUserDefaults()` works with sharing data between an app and extension does it? I am pretty sure that you must declare the group name..