# Today and main page file path not same for db?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, filepath

I'm creating sqlite in application and I wanna use in today page but they have different file path. I can't reach my db that reason.

It gives me path like this ~/Application on application but when i try to reach for today page ~/PlugIns/.. it happens like this.

How could i reach my db both of page, How can i do that. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can share data with path. Check this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32653801/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you.

Comment: @ErdiYILDIZ you are welcome