# Provisioning profile doesn't include the com.apple.security.application-groups entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-app-group

I am getting error while configuring Xcode provisioning profiles.

> Provisioning profile $ProfileName doesn't include the
> com.apple.security.application-groups entitlement.

How to fix it. It seems my provisioning profile/certificate does not have some capabilities. How/where to add those capabilities?

[image]

### update

In marked duplicated post, [Sharing data in between apps in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652795/sharing-data-in-between-apps-in-ios) the poster asked for generic way to share data between apps but in this post i am asking to resolve a specific build error i am getting while sharing data in between groups.

Comment: Do you actually want to use App Group(s)?

Comment: Yes i want to use

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First you have to set the app group up in the Apple Developer Center for your App ID:

[image]

Afterwards in Xcode:

- Select your target
- Enable "App Groups" in the "Capabilities" tab
- Tick the checkmark for the App Groups you want to use:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you also enable App Groups in your App ID in Apple Developer Center

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, X-code stuck.  please use manually sign-in instead of auto sign-in.
it may help .