# How to save file in shared app group on iOS and read from it

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, ios-app-group

I'm saving my data from my main app in a file that is stored somewhere in userDomainMask.

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(stops, toFile: BusStop.ArchiveURL.path)
```

and this is in my BusStop class file

```
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("stops")
```

Now I want to read this data from my Today Extension and its returning empty set [], so I know where the issue is. I need to save this data in a shared app group that my both Extension and App belongs to.

How do I save data and read from it?

## I want to save an array of instances of my BusStop class.

EDIT:

I fixed my problem!

Use this solution:

```
static let ArchiveURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.asd.asd.asd")!
    .appendingPathComponent("mypath")
```

and every time you are doing some operation on already saved data or you are saving new content use this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37162883/3595696

Cheers!

Comment: did you store your file in document directory ?

Comment: @KKRocks yeah, its there static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

Comment: why did you use archiveRootObject for this ?

Comment: @KKRocks This code was from apple tutorial In the saveMeals() method, add the following line of code:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1

Answer (score 6):

Setup the App Group in Apple Developer Center and enable the entitlement ([here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41876463/1457385)).

Then get the the App Groups URL:

```
guard let groupURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: applicationGroupId) else {
    fatalError("could not get shared app group directory.")
}
```

and use it to store common files in.

Comment: how to implement it?

Comment: What do you mean? Save everything you want to share to `groupURL`. Which implementation part are you missing?