# Can iOS14 widget requests main app to update its data?

Tags: swift, widget, ios14, widgetkit

my app needs latest data but, possibly, the main app has old data.

so i want to request to the main app to update its data.

is it possible?

if it is not I would like to know any alternative way.

(should the widget requests latest data to the server??)

thanks

===
UPDATE

I found many tutorials and all of them use http request from `getTimeline` method for getting newest data (not from the main app). it is not what i want.

Someone said easest way for sharing data between main app and widgets is using UserDefaults. But the data can be old if the main app does not update userdefaults values or update values using old data. (beside server data is always latest data)

So what i want to know is the way 'widget makes main app updates its data and updates userdefault and call `reloadTimelines`. so widget can use latest data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way for a Widget to tell its parent App to refresh its data.

You can either:

- fetch data directly in the Widget - see: [How to refresh Widget data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63976424/8697793)
- enable background notifications in the App (see [How to run code when your app is terminated](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-is-terminated)) and, when received one, force the Widget to refresh its timeline using:

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

In reality it's probably better to just fetch data directly in the Widget. This way you can fetch only the *necessary* data - Widget views usually display a lot less information than App views.

Comment: after few days of research I wrote all server communication code from widget code. haha. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can like this;
When you create a TimelineProvider for widget update, you have to implement this func,

```
 func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ())
```

This function waits to create your widget update timeline. You can sen a request, after the response, you can create a timeline and return func's completion.

Comment: thanks . But it is little bit different what I want to know. I edited my questions. thanks again.

Comment: Widget is like a 'separate' app on your iPhone. It cannot ask its parent app to wake-up and fetch new data. You either fetch new data from the widget directly, or you wait until the parent app is being opened by the user, fetched new data and then saves it into `UserDefaults(suiteName: "your.suiteName")`

Comment: Yep. now I'm pretty sure that I have to request to the server directly if I really need use latest data. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an App Group and store the database in that shared group directory. That way, if you update data in the main app or in the widget, those new data are available for both, it's not necessary to call the other one to load the same data again. Just be aware that you should still use

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

after you updated the data in your main app to refresh the widget immediately. Just have some handling for when the last request was performed, so you don't create an unnecessary request in your widget, and instead fetch them from the database.

If you move your request-performing code into a modul, you can also use it in the widget, as you do in your app. Finally you'll just have another call of the same updating code you are used to from your main app.

Since I don't have any of your code to update and present here, I'll just link some helpful sources for the way to the described destination.

[Apple Documentation: Configuring App-Groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups?changes=latest_minor)

[Sharing data within App-Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652795/sharing-data-in-between-apps-in-ios)