# iOS - letting another app edit and save files my app created, in the same folder where the file was opened from

Tags: ios, file, sandbox, shared

I would like to know if it is possible to let another iOS app open a file my app has created and then the other app edits and saves it just in the original location where my app had saved it at creation time. Or, instead, are files opened with the NSUrl in UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey just read-only so they just can be saved in the other app sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit other apps sandbox, it's private to your own app (except for the Documents folder, that a user can access from iTunes).

You also don't have access to the file system of the phone.

Welcome to iOS :)

Comment: Isn't it possible for a shared folder from my app too?

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561471/how-to-share-files-between-2-local-ios-apps-without-url-scheme-or-external-serve

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is a [custom URL scheme.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18) The other option would be [iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH2-SW1), but I think the URL scheme is the way to go here.

**Edit** I see the link doesn't work correctly, not sure why, just scroll the page down to the *Communicating with Other Apps* paragraph.

Comment: My app doesn't need to open those files, it just needs that another app edits and saves some files my app has in its shared folder.

Comment: There is no such thing as *shared folder*. If you have the access to both applications' sources, I'd suggest using iCloud then.

Comment: I mean the folder that the user can access through iTunes, it seems a sort of shared folder. So according to you that folder is not accessible from another app to save a file that comes from there and that my app sent it through UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey.

Comment: As far as I know this only allows sharing your Documents directory with the computer on which iTunes is installed, not with another application on the actual device.

Comment: so I suppose there is no user "Documents", that is a general folder on the device which any app can access to.

Comment: No, although it's possible to share files not directly using the techniques I mentioned in my answer. If you are new to iOS I'd suggest you read about [Sandboxing and other topics in the iOS Environment document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html).