# How to get Youtube URL into IPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiwebview

I'm developing an app were I would like to get youtube video url into my app from youtube app in IPhone. Whenever user clicks on video in youtube app that video's link should be directly retrieved into my app. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: check this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087249/save-youtube-video-to-iphone-in-the-app

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the data from some other app to your app...IOS doesnot allow it. All apps has their own separate documents directories. Only Media Files/contacts in phone are accessible.

Read this you might get some idea : [Is it possible to access data across 2 different iOS apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920181/is-it-possible-to-access-data-across-2-different-ios-apps)